# Checking linux version in compile time or runtime

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, runtime, compile-time

I use the function 'prctl' which was introduced in Linux 2.1.57.
I do the following:

```
    ...
        // function 'prctl' is linux only and was introduced in  version
        #ifdef __linux__
            #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,1,57)
                prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL);
            #endif
        #endif
    ...
```

But what will happen if i run my binary in lower version of linux ?
Programm will crash or not load ?

Do i need replace compile time checking by runtime (with utsname()->release )
or use both compile and runtime checking

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Linux 2.1.57 is a quite old version (1999). Most linux kernels are newer than that. I would just suppose, on Linux, that `prctl` exists...

Comment: The [`uname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) function might be a good start.

Comment: Basile, yes, your suggestion is suitable in principle. But i little don't understand if i run on older version programm will crash (segfault) ?

Comment: How do you know that the linux version your program was compiled with will be the same it actually runs with?

Comment: if i run my binary in lower version of linux - first, you must compile your program for this version of Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile your program on modern Linux but try to run it on older one, there are 2 possibilites:

1. Program was compiled dynamically. In this case, most likely it won't even load - because it will be linked to modern glibc version, which would not exist on older Linux system.
2. Program was compiled statically (meaning necessary glibc calls were bundled with your executable, making it larger). In that case, it will load, but most likely either crash, exit prematurely or simply skip offending call.

At any rate, it will not work normally.

Comment: It was compiled dynamically. Yes, you are right, I forgot about old version glibc on older linux. Now i decided just to use <pre>__linux__<pre> macros without checking version. In any case my code is temporary and i'll try to replace it by some posix compatable in the future. Thanks to all for help. Post can be closed.

Comment: This question has some value to you and to the community - why should it be closed? And if you think this answer helped you, then you should accept it - accepting increases your reputation as well